# why icon widget wont accept null?

Tags: flutter, button, widget, icons

i created a button widget and i want the  icon of my button  to be optional. so when i wanna write condition for it ,it wont accept it. here is my code:

> ```
> import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
>
> Widget CustomButtom({
>   String? title,
>   EdgeInsetsGeometry? paddin,
>   EdgeInsetsGeometry? margin,
>   double? width,
>   double? height,
>   Color? backgroundColor,
>   dynamic? onPress,
>   Color? fontColor,
>   double? fontsize,
>   double borderRaidius = 10,
>   bool showIcon = true,
>   Icon? buttonIcons,
> }) {
>   return Container(
>     width: width,
>     height: height,
>     child: Directionality(
>       textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
>       child: ElevatedButton.icon(
>         style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
>             backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
>             shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
>               borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRaidius),
>             )),
>         onPressed: onPress,
>         icon: showIcon? buttonIcons!:null,
>         label: Text(
>           '$title',
>           style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
>         ),
>       ),
>     ),
>   );
> }
> ```

and this is the error im getting

**The argument type 'Icon?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'.**

Comment: You need to use IconData? icon in params and inside button i.e. icon: showIcon? Icon(buttonIcons!):null,

Comment: "why?". That's just the way it is. `icon` is not allowed to be `null`. Don't use `ElevatedButton.icon` if you don't want an icon

Comment: this is widget i create in utility folder i wanna be able to keep using it

Comment: or provide a default icon on null case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest splitting it up to two different widgets then. Use a normal `ElevatedButton` when there's `showIcon` false, like:

```
return Container(
  width: width,
  height: height,
  child: Directionality(
    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
    child: showIcon
        ? ElevatedButton.icon(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRaidius),
                )),
            onPressed: onPress,
            icon: buttonIcons!,
            label: Text(
              '$title',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
          )
        : ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRaidius),
                )),
            onPressed: onPress,
            child: Text(
              '$title',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ),
  ),
);
```

Note that you will get an exception when you have `showIcon` as `true` but `buttonIcons` as `null`. Maybe it's better to leave out the `showIcon` and just check on `buttonIcons` being `null` or not to decide between the two. So like:

```
return Container(
  width: width,
  height: height,
  child: Directionality(
    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
    child: buttonIcons != null
        ? ElevatedButton.icon(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRaidius),
                )),
            onPressed: onPress,
            icon: buttonIcons,
            label: Text(
              '$title',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
          )
        : ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRaidius),
                )),
            onPressed: onPress,
            child: Text(
              '$title',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ),
  ),
);
```